# How to get information about contents of Qt listbox in another process

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, accessibility, cross-process

I got an application written using Qt and I would like to read data in Qt listbox.
It doesnt respond to LB_GETTEXT or other windows messages, is there a good way to get data from it from another process?

I have no access to Qt process, its external program. I am looking for a way to access LB contents from C#.

As it turns out there is Accessibility plugin for Qt that is supposed to provide support for required operations. However I am noob with QT and its unclear to me whether application has to be build with accessibility allowed or its a feature that can be turned on and off for any application ( or at least default build applicaiton, with accessibility not being disabled explicitly).

I have read and it says you need to run export QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1, place qt.conf file and put accessible folder to Qt app in main root. I think I dont understand completely how to turn QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1 and whever it should be enough for application to become accessible. ive added QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1 into environment variables in my computer properties, should that do the trick? Or export QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1 is something different.

Thanks

Comment: This is very interesting question. Could you find something useful? I know about [funq](https://github.com/parkouss/funq) and [GammaRay](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/wiki/Getting-GammaRay). But they don't look like the best choice for black box QT GUI automation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use interprocess communication for these purposes: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/ipc.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I wasn't clear enough, I am not the creator of Qt written process, its external program that I want to use from my C# program , and if I understand correctly your link doesn't provide ways to do that.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that you had acces to the Qt program :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily do that, since Qt doesn't use standard Windows controls to implement it's widgets, thus you can't easily access it's contents using standard Windows Api methods(functions/messages/windows ipc). You will need to somehow hack trough it's memory(not really recommended) or use some gui (testing) automation tool that supports Qt like [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/products/index.php).

**LE:** You might also want to check this hack by forcing the loading of Qt Accessible Plug-in 
into the application and then trying to inspect using usual tools like Microsoft's Spy++ included in Visual Studio. See [1](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/qt-accessible-plugin.html) and [2](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/accessible.html).

Comment: is there a way to access Qt contents from Qt application? maybe they respond to some Qt cross process messages? (if you understand what I am saying). Maybe I could create a Qt program that would be an adapter betwen calls from my C# app to > my Qt program > make Qt calls to external process? Or that is not possible either

Comment: Not possible as long as you don't have access to that apps source code, since every Qt IPC method must be connected/accepted and handled at the source level.

Comment: Oki ill wait a little for some magic answer maybe and will grant you the bounty with sad face :) wanted some way to do the magic without much problems. How does Squish Qt version work then? if you know ( I mean how will IT interact with QT ListBox)

Comment: It most probably takes that ugly hack trough the applications memory approach that i mentioned above.

Comment: Take a look at http://qt.nokia.com/products-kr/device/qt-extended-modules/qt-ui-test-module/ though i think it refers to the Nokia Mobile Qt edition.

Comment: Very very interesting. I think this is getting close to some good solution. Did you ever try using this accessibility module? Is there a way for a Qt program to prevent it from working? If "hack" is installed how that would simplify my goal to read data from listbox? It would start to respond to WM_Gettext messages or ? I am excited, but I dont think I fully understand this accessibility module..

Comment: Unfortuately this cannot be really considered as answer, if Qt isnt built in Accessible mode.